# String index is out of range

Tags: java

```
import java.io.*;
public class Program
{
    public static void main(String args[])throws IOException
    {
        InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader (System.in);
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader (isr);
        int i, len;
        char ch;
        String rev = "";
        System.out.println("Enter a String:");
        String str = br.readLine();
        len = str.length();
        for(i=len; i>=0; i--)
        {
            ch = str.charAt(i);
            rev = rev + ch;
        }
        System.out.println("Reversed String is: " +rev);
    }
}
```

The program works fine until I press enter after the input.
e.g. 
Enter a String:

java

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String index out of range: 5
at java.lang.String.charAt(String.java:658)
at Program.main(Program.java:16)
Java Result: 1
```

I tried compiling it in NetBeans. Please explain.

Comment: Did you mean to write `i=len-1`?

Comment: Yes, it will. Because the index starts at 0 , not at 1.

Answer (score 1):

Use `for(i=len-1; i>=0; i--)` rather than `for(i=len; i>=0; i--)`, otherwise `str.charAt(i)` will beyond the last character of your string during the first iteration of for-loop.

```
String str = "ABCDE";   // for example
int len = str.length(); // 5

"ABCDE"  (your string)
 01234   (index)

str.charAt(0) // 'A'
str.charAt(len-1)  // 'E'
str.charAt(len)    // StringIndexOutOfBoundsException occurs
```

[DEMO](https://ideone.com/uQLDD5)

Comment: or like this: `for (i = len; --i >= 0;) { /* ... */ }`

Answer (score 0):

Please consider using reverse() method of StringBuffer:

```
import java.io.*;
public class Program
{
    public static void main(String args[]) throws IOException
    {
        InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader (System.in);
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader (isr);
        System.out.println("Enter a String:");
        StringBuffer sbInput = new StringBuffer(br.realLine());
        System.out.println("Reversed String is : " + sbInput.reverse());
    }
}
```